# Offline bundling in debug mode for iOS on React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using Firebase App Distribution feature to send my co-workers some production builds, so I need an .ipa file but I'm having trouble generating it with offline bundling on debug mode for iOS.

To generate the bundle (main.jsbundle), I run this command:

```
react-native bundle --dev true --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

The way I'm generating the .ipa is by archiving the app in xcode on debug mode and distributing for "Developers".

[Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m95u4.jpg)

In the end, when I download the app via Firebase, it requires for the bundler to be running, it is not a stand-alone app. Does anyone have an idea on whats happening?

Comment: Hi, I believe if you are attempting to build and release through the Firebase App Distribution platform, you will need to make a RELEASE version (not a dev) version of you app. You'll likely want to use Xcode to make an archive, then build an AD-HOC version of your app. Too, you'll want to ensure you have the UDID for every device you want to distribute to as well.

Comment: @JasonGaare Thanks for the quick answer! The distribution works fine for a release (production) version of the app, I have done it a couple of times, but on debug mode it requires for the bundle to be runing.

Comment: Right, I do not believe there is a way to use a pre-packaged bundle with debug mode, that I'm aware of

Comment: @JasonGaare I understand now, thank you so much

Comment: @JasonGaare Do you know any way to distribute the app to my co-workers in debug mode? just so process.env.NODE_ENV returns me "development"